# CakePHP - use Controller as Data Access Layer

Tags: cakephp, model, dao, controllers

I have model which is used as source for generating dynamic menu on pages. I'd like to reduce code duplication in different controllers which display menu. Can I create controller that contains general utility methods for extracting information from database and reuse that controller in other controllers? Can I use controller similar to DAO object? I think it could be really handy to have middle layer object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want but

> reuse that controller in other controllers

is why we have [Components](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Component.html). Create your own Component and use it in your Controllers.

(I would put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: Can also use AppController::beforeRender for the kind of logic described in the question